# Mongo update an array property for every array item in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Consider the following collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6575b267334a021919f016"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "state" : "Created",
            "requestedQuantity" : 145,
            "startDateTime" : 1550153068155,
            "endDateTime" : null,
        }
    ],
    "code" : "229395",
    "state" : "Waiting",
    "comments" : "",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c65761667334a021919f018"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "state" : "Created",
            "requestedQuantity" : 132,
            "startDateTime" : 1550153144703,
            "endDateTime" : null,
        }
    ],
    "code" : "229396",
    "state" : "Waiting",
    "comments" : "",
}
```

I want to update the `state` property inside my items to `Done` no matter what `state` is the item in:

```
db.orders.update({"items.state": { $ne: "Done"}}, {$set: {"items.$.state": "Done"}},{"multi": true});
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 2,
        "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query."
    }
})
```

Why I'm getting the above error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which requires corresponding query to match single element in an array. To update all states you can use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator instead:

```
db.orders.updateMany({}, { $set: { "items.$[].state": "Done" } })
```

EDIT: in your example you have specified filtering criteria albeit as per documentation:

> If the query matches the array using a negation operator, such as $ne, $not, or $nin, then you cannot use the positional operator to update values from this array.

Answer (score 1):

Using positional operator you can use array filters (if you're filtering based on that array) on the field:

```
db.orders.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "items.$[e].state" : "Done" } },
   { multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "e.state": { $ne: "Done" } } ]
   }
);
```